# IntelliJ IDEA highlighting code between bracket with the line on the left side

Tags: intellij-idea, colors, settings, brackets

Hey guys im trying to highlighting LEFT side of code between the selected brackets, but cant really find the solution in the settings... Can somebody help me out on this ?

[image: Green line on the left side is barely seenly]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Editor | Guides | Indent guide selected.

[image: Indent guide selected]